# How many nails can be in a floor joist before it's a problem?

Tags: floor, joists, blocking, hanger

This sounds like a weird question but I can't find an answer online to it. We have a non-loadbearing partition wall that is sitting parallel to but *between* two joists. In between the joists, there is some existing blocking that the wall is sitting on. The blocking isn't secured with the right nails (they're screwshank nails for subflooring) and we're planning on putting cabinets on this wall so a good bit of weight will be added. Here's a rough sketch of what this looks like currently:

[image: current]

I'd like to shore up this blocking with some hangers and proper 10d nails, but I'm a bit worried that the number of nails in the joist might begin to pose a problem. The hangars are going to add at least 4-6 nails around each block and with the pre-existing ones being so close I'm worried the integrity of the joist might be compromised. As a visual aid, each the side view will look like something like this after adding hangers to the joints:

[image: with-hangers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placement of the nails is more important than number.

If you drive the nails in so they start splitting off chunks of joist then you have a problem.

If the nails are spaced out, then imagine a joist can hold thousands of nails without causing a problem except with a compass/stud finder.

Comment: How spaced out is "spaced out?" The additional nails for the hangers would be a few inches apart from the existing nails.

Comment: That should be plenty.  Just do not want to drive them side by side and cause a possible split.

Comment: @monitorjbl the joist hangars have been quite rigorously tested with the exact number and spacing of nails each one requires. If that were _too many_ nails, it's most likely that would have been found during testing. Unless you're putting the blocking in so close that the flanges of the joist hangars are touching, you're not going to have anything to worry about. Even if you do put them in that close, my only concern would be for your wallet.